# How to Upgrade multiple Ubuntu 14 to 16

Tags: 14.04, server, upgrade, do-release-upgrade, fabric

I need some recommendation for upgrading multiple ubuntu.
I have to upgrade my Ubuntu 14 server to Ubuntu 16. I know how to upgrade.
My problem is the server is not only one, over 10 servers, so i don't want to do apt-update, apt-upgrade , do-release-upgrade ... for each server.

Is there any way to upgrade multiple server with one command line?
Is is possible with fabric?

Thanks

Comment: At work we use [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html) for installing and upgrading. I don't know if upgrading to a new ubuntu release will work with it, but I think it should and is worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation,,i'll check Ansible